# Initialize Datetime from String

Tags: python

I have strings like this `Wed Mar 18 19:24:07 +0000 2020`

I guess it should be ,,,

```
%a %b %d %X %z %Y
```

However , how can I put this in python datetime class??

Comment: You can use `strptime()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and the [codes from here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) :

```
value = "Wed Mar 18 19:24:07 +0000 2020"
d = datetime.strptime(value, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
print(d)  # 2020-03-18 19:24:07+00:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the string as a datetime object.

Comment: Thanks you I use strptime()